# Why does the ElasticSearch Nest client throw invalid_shape_exception for MultiPolygonGeoShape

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, geo

I am trying to use the Nest package to insert multiple shapes into ElasticSearch geo_shape field.

Initially I used a Nest.PolygonGeoShape which worked fine for single shapes but when I had multiple shapes elastic would throw

```
invalid_shape_exception: Invalid shape: Hole is not within polygon
```

I read up on it and found that a Polygon with multiple shapes is treated as an outer shape and 'holes'. However a MultiPolygon is treated as a collection of separate shapes.

I switched to a GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.MultiPolygon type (accidentally used one from the wrong namespace) and it worked fine. Inserted fine, deserialised fine also.

Noticing the namespace, I switched to Nest.MultiPolygonGeoShape and the original error returned.

I would prefer to use the types from the contract Nest defines.

Why is ElasticSearch not treating my MultiPolygonGeoShape as individual shapes?

Comment: Can you provide the shape? link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) if it's really large

Comment: thanks @RussCam - printing the request out showed the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The difference is actually in the population of the object. I checked the underlying request (thanks @Russ Cam) and these are the differences in the polygons structure (simplified).

```
[
    [
        [
            [0.26337, 51.85278], [0.26473, 51.8509] ...
        ]
    ], 

    [
        [
            [-2.73905, 53.75779], [-2.7259, 53.75786] ...
        ]
    ], 

    [
        [
            [-2.6594, 53.7622], [-2.66654, 53.76121] ...
        ]
    ]
],



[
    [
        [
            [0.26337, 51.85278], [0.26473, 51.8509] ... 
        ]
    ], 

    [
        [
            [-2.73905, 53.75779], [-2.7259, 53.75786] ...
        ],  
        [
            [-2.6594, 53.7622], [-2.66654, 53.76121] ...
        ]
    ]
],
```

The first worked, the second didn't. That's because the first is treated as 3 separate polygons, the second as two polygons - one with a hole. This is true even in a MultiPolygonGeoShape.

Comment: To clarify, is it an issue with the way `MultiPolygonShape` has been initialized?

Comment: Yes that's correct - in one case I was flattening the my collection, in the other I was not, and mapping to the IEnumerable<IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate>> was too much for my brain on friday afternoon. Thanks for responding though :)